# Is there a more elegant way for unpacking keys and values of a dictionary into two lists, without losing consistence?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

What I came up with is:

```
keys, values = zip(*[(key, value) for (key, value) in my_dict.iteritems()])
```

But I am not satisfied. What do the pythonistas say?

Comment: BTW notice that your list comprehension should ring alarm bells because it doesn't do anything -- no `if` clause to filter and no function being mapped either.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What about using [`my_dict.keys()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) and [`my_dict.values()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)?

```
keys, values = my_dict.keys(), my_dict.values()
```

Comment: You mean: `keys, values = dict.keys(), dict.values()`?

Comment: This works because one of the contracts with `dict` is that the order of keys and values within the dict will correspond as long as the size of the dict does not change.

Comment: @Constantinius: This is really elegant, thanks! @Ignacio: Thanks a lot! This was the enlightening I hoped for and destroys my concernes about the consistency of both lists, by what I meant ordering.

Comment: Warning: I'm pretty sure this isn't threadsafe (if that matters to you). Because dict.keys() is called separately from dict.values(), there's an opportunity for a race condition where the dict is modified between those calls. Unpacking dict.items() is safer here because it's a single function call and can't possibly return a different number of keys and values.

Comment: @Kirk, thank you. That is indeed good to know! I was only interested in preserving order, but I'll keep your advice in mind.

Comment: @Aufwind, according to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612769/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-for-unpacking-keys-and-values-of-a-dictionary-into-t#comment7805058_6612795), if the dict is modified between the calls to keys() and values() the order will *not* be preserved.  I think [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6612821/5419599) is better than this one.

Comment: Beware: dict.keys() and dict.values() won't return a list. You'll have to typecast it to list or set.
Like list(dict.keys())

Comment: @RohitTaneja: In Python 3 yes, in Python 2 (which I had in mind when writing this answer) both return lists.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. You do not end up with two lists, you have to cast to a list for this to answer the OPs original request

Comment: @Will.Evo At the time this answer was given, Python 3 was not yet released. And in Python 2, `.keys()` and `.values()` actually returned lists. But yeah, nowadays you have to convert these objects to lists first.

Answer (score 88):

```
keys, values = zip(*d.items())
```

Comment: `keys` and  `values` will be tuples... need to convert to lists after

Comment: you can do it like this: `[*keys],[*values] = zip(*d.items())`